# Css and Jquery not working properly in dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

It's been days that I am working on this issue, but I don't know how to resolve this. Can anyone help with this?

The problem is that I have two applications, While integrating the application together pages are not working as expected. Individually, they are working fine.

Here comes the problem, I am trying to load the 2nd application page in 1st application Jquery dialog. **Everything is loaded, but the css and jquery are not working**.

A Second application is Asp.net mvc application, there we are returning total html page instead of razor view.

I am attaching the code below.

```
 <div style="display: none; background-color: White; width: 100%; height: 
90%; border: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px !important; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
        id='approvalRulePopup'>

    </div>


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pData.URL,
    data: pData,
    dataType: "text",
    timeout: "60000",
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        $.unblockUI();

        if (textStatus == 'timeout')
            $.prompt(hashtable["consTimeoutError"].toString());

        if (textStatus == "error" && eval(XMLHttpRequest).responseText == "")
            $.prompt(hashtable["consTimeoutError"].toString());

    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#approvalRulePopup').empty();
        $('#approvalRulePopup').html(data);
        $.unblockUI();
    },
    complete: function () {

    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're loading an either page (view) rather than a snippet of html (partial view).  In which case, you probably want to put an iframe in your dialog and set the iframe's src to your 2nd page.  If you put the html of another application in your page, you'll be mixing the two css sets, with unpredictable results - by using an iframe you'll keep them completely separate.

Comment: I tried for this, but is there any option to give the src as URL with post action. Because we validating the user with some headers value

Comment: Thanks @freedomn.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for so many days, I resolved this issue by using iframe post.

Html Code :

```
<div style="display: none; background-color: White; width: 100%; height: 90%; border: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px !important; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
    id='divPopup'>
    <form id="formPopup" method="post" style="display: none;" target="Iframeone"
    action="">
    </form>
    <iframe src="" id="Iframeone" name="Iframeone" style="width: 97%; height: 90%; position: absolute;
        min-height: 540px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Jquery Code :

```
  function ProcessIFrameByPost(pData) {

// Pdata = Json data

// Getting the window height and width

var wWidth = $(window).width();
var dWidth = wWidth * 0.95;
var wHeight = $(window).height();
var dHeight = wHeight * 0.80;

// Creating jquery dialog

if (!$("#divPopup").hasClass("ui-dialog-content")) {

    $("#divPopup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: dWidth,
        height: dHeight,
        position: "center",
        enableMaximize: true,
        open: function (ev, ui) {
            ev.preventDefault();

        }
    });
}

 // Clearing previous data

$('#formPopup').html('');
$('#Iframeone').html('');

 // adding the action URL
$('#formPopup').attr("action", pData.URL);

// Appending the data to form 

for (var key in pData) {
    if (pData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", pData[key]);

        $('#formPopup').append(hiddenField);
    }
}

$('#divPopup').dialog('open');

$('#formPopup').submit();
}
```